# DIV tags display: inlineblock;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline

I am going to create 3 div tags the first two are adjacent to one another. 
The 3. Div tag is under the first two DIV tags.I have already done this, but I have inserted into the first div a slideshow, but then they are all become "display: block;".

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zpz9Y/)**

I already try to change the [code](http://file2.npage.de/012171/20/html/bjqs-1.3.min.js)...

Comment: try to use "display: inline-block !important;" in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will help:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.81);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #090909;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.box:hover {
    transition: background .3s;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
}
#news {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 693px;
}
#login {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 275px;
    left: 10px;
}
#info {
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 978px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 7.68%;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zpz9Y/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the float property. See the updated JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cZN8x/

By applying float left, and right on the two adjacent divs, they will fit alongside eachother - aslong as the total width is less that the container, which in this case doesn't matter. The one got'cha of using floats is the need to reset using a empty div with the CSS property

```
clear: both;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank u i got the problem with that but i have to change a little bit more too.